# parse HTML in python wxWidgets TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it possible, or is there a library that will allow me to parse HTML code inside the wx.TextCtrl widget?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use `myTextCtrl.GetValue()`, then parse the string with something like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html), [`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html), [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html), etc:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# lets say this is the text inside the TextCtrl:
# '<html><head><title>Page title</title></head><body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</html>'
#

htmlStr = myTextCtrl.GetValue()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlStr)
soup.contents[0].name
# u'html'

soup.contents[0].contents[0].name
# u'head'

head = soup.contents[0].contents[0]
head.parent.name
# u'html'

head.next
# <title>Page title</title>

head.nextSibling.name
# u'body'

head.nextSibling.contents[0]
# <p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>

head.nextSibling.contents[0].nextSibling
# <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</p>
```

Comment: i meant actually parse it within the wx text ctrl, for example if i color text in html, i want it to color the text in wx text ctrl

Comment: Oh, no, not directly.  Check out [The wxWebConnect Project - Web Browser Control Library for wxWidgets](http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect.html), that might be the best option.

Comment: nvm i solved it by using wx.html.HtmlWindow, now to just provide a click through event

Answer (score 0):

wxTextCtrl will display the HTML with all the tags

```
<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>");
```

To render the html, you need to use wxHtmlWindow

```
w = wxHtmlWindow(this)
w.SetPage("<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>")
```